# Authenticating Client on Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am very new to Mule and I want to know how we can authenticate a Client in our mule application. The flow has a HTTP listener. I have read Spring Security Manager can be used to authenticate a client but I am not able to find this option in the HTTP Listener. I am using Anypoint studio 5.4 . Please suggest how we can authenticate a client in Mule.

Comment: What type of authentication are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Spring security.
But you cannot simply configure it on the HTTP listener as you tried. You need to configure a few more things.

I will try to explain the simplest setup:

First outside your flow on a global level configure a authentication manager with something like:

```
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
              <ss:user name="admin" password="myadminpassword" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
          </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>
```

Note that to make the example as simple as possible (not good practice) I have inlined the user in the user service.

Now on the same global level outside your flow define the security manager referencing yout authentication manager

```
    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
```

Now inside your flow directly after your inbound endpoint (in your case HTTP listener) you add a http security filter like this:

```
     <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
```

Thats it. Try accessing your http/https endpoint and you will be challenged for username and password.

Note that there is a lot of flexibility and configuration options, this was just an simple example.

Also note that there are other types of Authentication possibilities available for you in Anypoint depending on your use case. For instance you might consider useing OAuth2 based authentication for your REST based endpoints...